# iphone: re-sizing gradient after shift from portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone, gradient

In *viewDidLoad*, I can create a gradient with no problem:

`CAGradientLayer *blueGradient = [[CAGradientLayer layer] retain];
blueGradient.frame = CGRectMake(gradientStartX,gradientStartY,gradientWidth,gradientHeight);`

where gradientWith is device-defined as 320 or 1024 as appropriate.

What I can’t do is resize it inside *willRotateToInterfaceOrientation*: -– and thus get rid of that empty black space off to the right -- after the user changes to landscape mode. (The nav bar and tab bar behave nicely.)

(1) Recalibrating the gradient’s new dimensions according to the new mid-point, (2) using kCALayerMaxXMargin, and (3) employing bounds all looked like they would do the job. bounds looked a litte more intuitive, so I tried that.

I don’t want to admit that I have made zero progress.

I will say that I’ve been reduced to the brute force method of trying every permutation of self, view, layer, bounds, blueGradient, and CGRect(gradientStartX,gradientStartY,newGradientWidth,newGradientHeight) with zero success.

This is not difficult.  My lack of understanding is making it difficult.  Anyone out there “Been there, done that”?

Answer (score 0):

Does the layer resize its size automatically? If so, simple

```
[blueGradient setNeedsDisplay];
```

should do the trick.

Hope this was helpful,
Paul

Comment: And you set resizing by either using the "springs and struts" view in IB, or setting the views contentMode property.

Comment: Paul -- Nope, no IB. I'm not doing anything with contentMode either. As we say on this side of the pond, "plain vanilla."
Pawel -- [blueGradient setNeedsDisplay] results in "blueGradient undeclared" 
Both -- Wow, fast responses! Thank you.

Comment: The blueGradient is the reference to your gradient layer - you need to keep in order to call it when the rotation is finished.